# Display Current Date as Lable Text using JavaScript in ASP.NET page C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to display the current date as a lable text using Javascript in a asp.net Page.

I want to display this on page load.
I don't want to use any c# code

I'm trying to get in the format "Wednesday, 01 August 2012"

Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you referring to the date on the server, or the date on the client's machine?

Comment: can i have from server because the date on the clients system might be changed

Comment: i'm trying from client system now but unsuccessful

Comment: can you tell me how to do it from client side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple Try jQuery :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

....

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>').val('<%=(System.DateTime.Now).ToString()%>');
  });
```

For Label :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= lblDate.ClientID %>').text('<%=(System.DateTime.Now).ToString()%>');
    });
```

....

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: How can i format it ?? like "Wednesday, 01 August 2012" 8:05:17 PM

Comment: When calling `ToString()` on a DateTime, you can pass in a parameter for the format: [MSDN: DateTime Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Comment: ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") Thank you

Comment: can we update the time every second?? like we do in silverlight

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any C# code at all, then I suggest you go for some jquery plugin.I would go for [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) plugin and you can display the date like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>').val(Globalize.format(new Date(),'D'));
  });
```

Hope this helps.